# Как проверить размещается ли точка координат в указанной области на mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, запрос, координаты

Возникла проблема в написании SQL запроса, нужна найти записи которые входят в зону с координатами, на php написать данный код не составило труда и он работает, но вот перевести на SQL мешает один фактор, координаты в колонке искомой точки хранятся в таком виде ***"46.4854932,30.2069585"***

```
$x = 46.4854932;
$y = 30.2069585;
if (empty($model->zone_coordinates) === false) {
    $zoneCoordinateNormalize = json_decode($model->zone_coordinates, true);

    $inside = false;
    for ($i = 0, $j = count($zoneCoordinateNormalize) - 1; $i < count($zoneCoordinateNormalize); $j = $i++) {
        $xi = $zoneCoordinateNormalize[$i]['lat'];
        $yi = $zoneCoordinateNormalize[$i]['lng'];
        $xj = $zoneCoordinateNormalize[$j]['lat'];
        $yj = $zoneCoordinateNormalize[$j]['lng'];
                    
        $intersect = (($yi > $y) != ($yj > $y)) && ($x < ($xj - $xi) * ($y - $yi) / ($yj - $yi) + $xi);

        if ($intersect === true) {
                $inside = !$inside;
        }
    }
}
```

По факту сама зона будет одна и мне нужно только привести данный `(($yi > $y) != ($yj > $y)) && ($x < ($xj - $xi) * ($y - $yi) / ($yj - $yi)` кусок в SQL, мне б узнать как можно с колонки при поисках в SQL получать значения после и перед комой, чтобы получить значения X и Y, если кто-то с чём-то подобным сталкивался, буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал решения, оказалось все просто, координаты отсоединил функцией mysql **SUBSTRING_INDEX**, а все остальное как на php:

```
if (empty($model->zone_coordinates) === false) {
    $zoneCoordinateNormalize = json_decode($model->zone_coordinates, true);

    $coordinatesQueryPieces = [];
    for ($i = 0, $j = count($zoneCoordinateNormalize) - 1; $i < count($zoneCoordinateNormalize); $j = $i++) {
         $xi = $zoneCoordinateNormalize[$i]['lat'];
         $yi = $zoneCoordinateNormalize[$i]['lng'];
         $xj = $zoneCoordinateNormalize[$j]['lat'];
         $yj = $zoneCoordinateNormalize[$j]['lng'];


         // Формула проверки вхожденния точки в вказаную зону ((yi > y) != (yj > y)) && (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi) и тогокое количиство вхождений должно быть не чотним
         $coordinatesQueryPieces[] = "
             IF(
                 (
                     (({$yi} > SUBSTRING_INDEX({{%object}}.coordinates, ',', -1)) != ({$yj} > SUBSTRING_INDEX({{%object}}.coordinates, ',', -1)))
                     AND (SUBSTRING_INDEX({{%object}}.coordinates, ',', 1) < ({$xj} - {$xi}) * (SUBSTRING_INDEX({{%object}}.coordinates, ',', -1) - {$yi}) / ({$yj} - {$yi}) + {$xi})
                 )
                 != 0,
                 1,
                 0
             )
        ";
    }

    if (empty($coordinatesQueryPieces) === false) {
        $coordinatesQueryAsString = implode(' + ', $coordinatesQueryPieces);

        $query->andWhere("(CASE ($coordinatesQueryAsString) % 2 WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

С текущей структурой - вам остаётся только скриптом перебирать ВСЕ записи, выполнить `$coords = explode(',', $координата);` и проверять скриптом.

А по хорошему - хранить `x` и `y` в отдельных столбиках

Comment: Нет, я уже почти нашёл решения, ближайшем часом его опубликую.